# Get number of columns in C++ with _bstr_t and ADO

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, bstr-t

I am using Visual Studio 2008, and SQL Server, Currently I have a connection using ADO, but would like to retrieve the number of columns a table has...

Here is what I have

```
/*CODE FOR connecting to database**/

/*query to know number of columns in table*/
_bstr_t sSQLd="Select Count(*) From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS Where TABLE_NAME='[dbo].[mytable]';";


/*define variable to hold number of columns and 
print number of coulms as an integer
*/
int COLS_PER_ROW = wcstod(sSQLd, NULL);
printf("COLS_PER_ROW: %d", COLS_PER_ROW);
```

It prints `0` although There are 20 columns in my table
How do I fix the query or the logic??

Comment: I don't see you executing that SQL; you appear to be attempting to convert the query itself to a number. It's gonna be zero.

Comment: @Roger Lipscombe: How do I add that, what instruction must be added in order to exec the `count`  with `Command.Execute ()`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the examples in this MSDN article will help: [How to: Convert Between Various String Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Quoting from the article:

> The strings types that are covered include char *, wchar_t*, _bstr_t,
>   CComBSTR, CString, basic_string, and System.String.

Convert from `_bstr_t` to `wchar_t*` or `char*` and then use [`strtol()/wcstol()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4z2wdyc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to convert it to `long`.

Comment: I was searching in the link you provided, and found out that there is no direct way to convert `_bstr_t` to `int`, what steps do you recommend to do that transform ? maybe using `atoi()`

Comment: If you have Boost installed, I would suggest using `boost::lexical_cast<>` (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) or else use `strtol()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4z2wdyc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)